# Is 'sonnance' a word or an error

Tags: sens

The video at the link below contains the phrase "une belle sonnance" in the subtitles at about 15:37. 'Sonnance' isn't in any of my dictionaries and I'm drawing a blank on Reverso and Linguee as well. The phrase "une belle sonnance" throws up only two google results for me, as does "une belle sonance". The sense in these results seems to be "an attractive sound".

What I hear in the video certainly sounds like 'sonnance', which is evidently what the subtitler heard as well, so I'm wondering whether the speaker perhaps means something else, for example "une belle assonance".

https://youtu.be/jJ4dJtkzNrM?t=936

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As you can see [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sonnance) (CNRTL), "sonnance" does not exist. I'll watch the video later and let you know, if you don't have any answer.

Comment: On trouve « c'est une belle sonnance » à partir de 15 mn 15 sec.

Comment: To the extent that a term's absence from *TLFi* shows that it doesn't exist,  perhaps its presence [here](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/sonnance) shows that it once did. (but I'm not sure if either of those two assertions is correct)

Comment: this word indeed does not seem to exist. But even in the subtitles it's written "sonnance".

Answer (score 5):

Effectivement, "Sonance" (sonnance) ne figure pas dans les dictionnaires généraux principaux. Cela ne l'empêche pas de se trouver dans la littérature, comme dans cet [ouvrage d'électroacoustique](https://books.google.fr/books?id=oX_TAAAAMAAJ&q=%22sonance%22&dq=%22sonance%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjypriQ8dviAhUMQhoKHflSCoc4ChDoAQg5MAQ) de 1948 dans lequel l'auteur en donne une définition très précise…

Cela étant, dans votre extrait il semble qu'il s'agisse simplement d'une divagation, le mot étant apparemment mis pour "sonorité" ou "son" au regard du contexte.

Answer (score 3):

"Sonnance", or "Sonance" are not French words, but errors.

He didn't mean "assonance" either.

"Assonance" is a French figure of speech.

Comment: Il faut les privilèges pour éditer sans permission, quand on pas la réputation il faut envoyer une suggestion de modification. Les suggestions ne sont pas acceptées si elles sont trop courtes, donc si c'est pour corriger une conjugaison ou une majuscule c'est pas possible. (Bon ok suiieriesesse a les privilèges mais de manière générale ça marche comme ça ^^ )

Comment: Oui, pardonnez mon commentaire (aussitôt supprimé). Merci pour l'edition.

Answer (score 3):

*Sonnance* is indeed not listed in dictionaries but was made up by Nicolas using regular French suffixation rules.

The word is a bit surprising to native French speakers but doesn't really make one cringe because the expected meaning is quite easy to guess.

Many words with the *-ance* or *-ence* suffixes are derived from adjectives/present participle in *-ant*, e.g.:

> Abondant  ↣ Abondance
>   Arrogant  ↣ Arrogance
>   Dominant  ↣ Dominance
>   Extravagant  ↣ Extravagance
>   Ignorant  ↣ Ignorance

In all of the previous examples, the *-ance* word means the quality of being *-ant* so from:

> *Sonnant* (sounding, ringing, chiming, tolling)

a word meaning the "quality of sounding" was coined:

> *Sonnance*, the quality of *bien sonner*.

We can draw a parallel between this technique and a notorious case whereby a former French Presidency candidate, Ségolène Royal, used *[bravitude](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bravitude)*. Everyone rightly understood it to mean *bravoure*, but this anecdote certainly didn't help her in the polls...

Comment: et voici comment des néologismes naissent :-)

Answer (score 1):

« Son(n)ance » n'existant pas , je pense qu'il a voulu dire « [sonorité](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sonorit%C3%A9). »

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, "sonnance" is an error. But after watching the video, I think this man wants to say something like "c'est une grâce et **un bel écho** que d'entendre cette voix interne qui nous dirige".

If so, the meaning is:

He has a voice, inside, who struggles against schizophrenia and while this voice is victorious, it's like a wonderful echo hearing this voice.

In other words, this voice sounds very nice, like a lovely sound. Accordingly you also may say "une belle sonorité".